# rename a file and only modify after dot

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to modify a test.tar.gz into test.tgz but it dosn't work. Here is the command:

```
temporalFolder= /home/albertserres/*.tar.gz
subprocess.call(["mv",temporalFolder,"*.tgz"])
```

It sends me error that the file doesn't exist. Why?

Also I just need to modify after the dot, not the entire name, because I'll probably doesn't know the file name, and if I do *.tgz it rename the file *.tgz and I want to keep the original name.

Comment: Have you tried executing this command in the command line? It will fail there too. You need to specify the target file name without `*`

Comment: In the command line it works, is just that it doesn't work on the subprocess.call

Comment: So you say that `mv /home/albertserres/*.tar.gz *.tgz` works for you? what operating system do you use?

Comment: `temporalFolder= /home/albertserres/*.tar.gz` is not a valid Python

Answer (score 2):

`rename` would probably be easier.

```
rename 's/\.tar\.gz/\.tgz/' *.tar.gz
```

In your case

```
params = "rename 's/\.tar\.gz/\.tgz/' /home/albertserres/*.tar.gz"
subprocess.call(params, shell=True)
```

Comment: beware, there are several `rename` commands e.g., [`rename` from `util-linux` package has different syntax](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
import shutil

orig_file = '/home/albertserres/test.tar.gz'
new_file = orig_file.replace('tar.gz', 'tgz')
shutil.move(orig_file, new_file)
```

And if you want to do that for several files:

```
import shutil
import glob

for orig_file in glob.glob('/home/albertserres/*.tar.gz'):
    new_file = orig_file.replace('tar.gz', 'tgz')
    shutil.move(orig_file, new_file)
```

Comment: It might replace `tar.gz` in the middle of the filename. Also if `new_file` happens to be a directory then `orig_file` is moved *inside* it instead of renaming. You could [use `os.rename()` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29438393/4279).

Answer (score 1):

To replace all `.tar.gz` file extensions with `.tgz` file extensions in a given directory (similar to [@hitzg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29413327/4279)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glob import glob

for filename in glob(b'/home/albertserres/*.tar.gz'):
    new = bytearray(filename)
    new[-len(b'tar.gz'):] = b'tgz'
    os.rename(filename, new) # or os.replace() for portability
```

The code replaces `tar.gz` only at the end of the name. It raises an error if `new` is an existing directory otherwise it silently replaces the file on Unix.